# rename_with doesn't work in purrr::map2 - Error "! the ... list contains fewer than 2 elements"

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, rename, purrr

Another seemingly easy task where `purrr::map2` is giving me a hard time.

I have a list of data frames and I have a vector of column names. I now want to rename a certain column in each of the data frames with the respective new column name. So I wanted to simply loop through it with `map2`, but am getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
new_names <- c("test1", "test2")

df_list <- list(data.frame(mtcars[, 1]),
                data.frame(mtcars[, 2]))

map2(.x = df_list,
     .y = new_names,
     .f = ~.x |> 
       rename_with(.cols = everything(),
                   .fn   = ~.y))

# Error in `map2()`:
# ℹ In index: 1.
# Caused by error in `.fn()`:
# ! the ... list contains fewer than 2 elements
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I also tried different variants of `.y`, e.g. `!!.y`, `paste0(sym(.y))` etc. in all possible combinations - no success.

Expected output would be the same list as the input, just that the first data frame has now a column "test1" and the second data frame a column "test2".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use anonymous functions with *purrr-style lambda* for both `.f` of `map2` and `.fn` of `rename_with`, and they conflict with each other. You need to explicitly specify an argument name, i.e. change `.fn = ~ .y` to `.fn = \(nms) .y`.

```r
map2(.x = df_list,
     .y = new_names,
     .f = ~ .x |> 
       rename_with(.cols = everything(),
                   .fn   = \(nms) .y))
```

Comment: I think it works also without `\(nms)` see starja's answer :)

Comment: @Julian No, @starja re-write `new_names` as a list of functions. But I do not.

Comment: Ah true! Now I understand why it is necessary to explicitly specify an argument name, thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 issues:

- `rename_with` expects a function, not a vector
- the error you get is from using `~.y`, while only `.y` works. I guess it's due to hiccups in the evaluation from purrr/dplyr

You can use your code if you provide a list of functions as inputs:

```
new_names <- list(function(x) {"test1"}, function(x) {"test2"})

df_list <- list(data.frame(mtcars[, 1]),
                data.frame(mtcars[, 2]))

map2(.x = df_list,
     .y = new_names,
     .f = ~.x %>%  
       rename_with(.cols = everything(),
                   .fn   = .y))
```

Alternatively, I'd just use `colnames`:

```
new_names <- c("test1", "test2")

df_list <- list(data.frame(mtcars[, 1]),
                data.frame(mtcars[, 2]))

map2(.x = df_list,
     .y = new_names,
     .f = function(df, new_name) {
       colnames(df)[1] <- new_name
       df
     })
```

Comment: Re rename_with expecting a function...yes, but it expects the function to return a character vector, so passing a character vector with `~my_vector` should be no problem. I think the problem is rather what @Darren Tsai described, i.e. the confusion of the names of the function argument by nesting map2 and rename_with. But interesting approach with passing the names as functions.

Comment: I see, I think you are right. Yes, it's an interesting approach, but I'd say rather cumbersome to have to type out the functions.

Answer (score 4):

We can use numbers on the right hand side of `rename()` to specify which column number we want to rename, so I would just use  `map2()` and `rename()` (instead of `rename_with`).

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2(df_list,
     new_names,
     \(df, col) rename(df, !! col := 1)
     )

#> [[1]]
#>    test1
#> 1   21.0
#> 2   21.0
#> 3   22.8
#> 4   21.4
#> 5   18.7
#> ...
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    test2
#> 1      6
#> 2      6
#> 3      4
#> 4      6
#> 5      8
#> ...
```

Data from OP

```r
new_names <- c("test1", "test2")

df_list <- list(data.frame(mtcars[, 1]),
                data.frame(mtcars[, 2]))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>